# Learning how the answer to a question works

Tags: discussion

I recently had a question answered satisfactorily after a little back and forth refinement with the person who answered it.  It works!  Yay!  But for the life of me, I can't figure out *how.*  I'm going to need to make some very minor adjustments to the code, and feel like I would rather learn how the code I already have works so that I can tinker my own solution rather than open up a whole new question.  Where would be a good place to ask for and receive a bit of explanation on something that's not broken?

Plus, that way I may be able to help others with similar problems and benefit the community as a whole.

For example, here is the piece of code I would like feedback on:

```
grouped = data.groupby(['teamname', 'members']).first()

results = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

for t in grouped.itertuples():
    for i, key in enumerate(t.Index):
        if i ==0:
            nested = results[key]
        elif i == len(t.Index) -1:
            nested[key] = t
        else:
            nested = nested[key]


formattedJson = json.dumps(results, indent = 4)
```

My specific questions would be:  in regard to the "results=" statement, 1.  What is the function of a defaultdict whose default is another defaultdict(dict) ?  2.  I don't see anyplace where anything is written to the "results" object, yet that is the object that is eventually dumped into the JSON.

In regards to the "for" loop, 3.  In the (t.Index) of each tuple, what do the "i" and "key" refer to?  4.  I don't understand the mechanics of the if-elif-else arguments and would simply like an explanation of what's going on there.

Comment: Could you write the question you're thinking of asking *in this question*? It's hard to make a judgement in the abstract!

Comment: Are you suggesting that right here on Meta is the place I should be asking how a piece of code works?

Comment: @spaine yes, but, for the purpose of us critiquing the question and/or deciding whether or not it is appropriate/where, not answering it.

Comment: Okay, I added a code sample - where would be a good place to learn how it functions?

Comment: If you have questions about specific aspects of the code that would be very helpful.  Also include what you think is happening, so that answerers have an idea of what's you need help with.

Comment: I will definitely flesh out the question about the code - I just wanted to know the proper place to ask it.

Comment: My suspicion is that most of those questions will already be answered, for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/8419401/3001761, or could be answered by running the code with a few extra `print`s in. That said, if you have a specific question (#4 in particular would need a lot of work if you can't find it or figure it out) that doesn't fall into either of those categories I think it would be OK on SO.